# How to run chromium as root

Tags: chromium

How do I run chrome as root in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: You do realize you open your system up for anyone on the outside trying to get into your machine using a possible exploit?

Comment: Rinzwind is right - it's a big security hole. There's whole sort of javascript  malware that can hide on websites, and by running any browser as root you're just yelling "Heeeeey, over here, hack me! "

Answer (score 5):

Open google-chrome located in `/usr/bin` with 'gedit', 'kate' or your favorite text editor:

```
sudo gedit /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Add `--user-data-dir` (without the quotes) at the very end of the file. Mine looks like this:

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir
```

Save, close and voilà, you're done. You can open chrome as root now.

Comment: Question was _How do I run **chrome** as a root user in Ubunut 12.04??_ Hence my answer

Comment: Title states chromium so I took that one (and cuz chromium is in the repos and chrome aint ;) ). Lets see who wins by upvotes :D (here have one from me ;) ) edit: I removed the html tags :)

Comment: So we can consider this a tie after 1.5 years :-D

Answer (score 3):

**DISCLAIMER/Warning: Running anything as root is risky and you should not run any software as root when you don't have to. If you don't know what you're doing, or are on a system that needs to be secure, STOP READING NOW**

This is about this message:

[image]

And you need to hex edit chromium:

```
sudo apt-get install hexedit
cd /usr/lib/chromium-browser
sudo cp chromium-browser chromium-browser.backup
hexedit chromium-browser
```

Do control+s and search for `geteuid`; change it to `getppid` and control-x to exit.

And you can start chromium as root.

To revert the change:

```
cd /usr/lib/chromium-browser
sudo cp chromium-browser.backup chromium-browser
```

Comment: What is geteuid?

Comment: See http://linux.die.net/man/2/geteuid

Comment: when I tried to search using `ctrl+S` for `geteuid` it shows invalid hexa string

Answer (score 1):

Edit file `/etc/chromium-browser/default`.

Add line `CHROMIUM_FLAGS=" --user-data-dir"`.

You are done. Launch Chromium.

Comment: Note that since a Chromium update, this solution no longer works. It worked in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
chromium --no-sandbox
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Ubuntu on both Nexus 7 (Ubuntu 13.04) and x86 PC (Ubuntu 15.10) running as root:

```
chromium-browser --temp-profile
```

Help gives this:

```
--temp-profile          Start with a new and temporary profile
```

(Nexus 7 had other but presumably unrelated issues)

This answer was supposed to be a comment as this may not be true for 12.04, but I can't comment as a forum newbie.

Usual warning: Running as root is dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

Simple rly. Fastest way. But this isn't recomended.

```
chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/home/someuser
```

Comment: Explain why it isn't recommended.

Comment: Security reasons. :)

Comment: Why downvote? I use `--user-data-dir=/root/.data` If I want to use root user, and I don't see any reasonable security concerns.